# Making a drop down list that filters out certain model objects in Django

Tags: jquery, python, django, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a page that lists all objects of a certain model, but also has a dropdown on top that filters the list based what was selected in the dropdown. Below is some example code.

models.py

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    slug_name = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
```

tables.py

```
class StudentTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'school')
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-hover', 'id': 'accessorycharge_list'}
```

Below is what the view would look like without the dropdown list.

views.py

```
def list_students(request):
    student_list = Student.objects.all()
    table = StudentTable(student_list)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'students/list_students.html', {'table': table})
```

In this example, I would theoretically want to make a dropdown in the same template as the list. The dropdown would contain the names of the schools. When nothing is selected, the list will show all of the students, but once a school is selected in the dropdown, the list would be filtered and only the students that have their school field match the one selected in the dropdown would be shown. How would I write my view and/or template in order to make this function? Thanks.

Comment: I tried making it function like a search, but apparently the search function ends up causing an error. I think it has something to do with foreign keys.

Comment: I think you are using `django-tables2` app, in that case you should specify it in your question to make better your question and easier answer you, and maybe the easy way to achive all this you want is using `django-filter` app